# Best way to listen for an event in c#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I need to make a small listener utility that "listens" for audio activity and performs an action when it detects sound.

At the moment I am just using a while loop:

```
        MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDevice device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);

        float level = 0;
        while (level == 0)
        {
            // Get current audio level
            level = device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Audio Detected");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This works OK, but given I want this utility to be "always on" in the background, I want to make sure I am doing this in the most efficient manner.

Is this bad practice? Should I be creating an EventHandler, and if so, how do I do it?

To give a bit more detail about the requirements, when the utility detects audio I want it to resize a window. (It's a video conference window in a browser which should stay minimised. When a third party joins the call and starts to speak, I want the window to maximise. When the user finishes the call they will just minimise the window again, and I want to the listener app to continue listening for the next time a user joins the call.)

Comment: Is that the MMDevice from the NAudio project?

Comment: It is depending to your requrirements? if you want to publish the changes then you can use EventHanlders or Action. Events are messages the object can raise when a particular condition is 
met

Comment: It is indeed. Saved me a whole heap of work!

Comment: From the quick look I took at the NAudio code I would guess you'd have to use a thread to sample the audio data and look for peak values if you want to run that in the background. What you do *inside* that thread is up to you, you could expose an event and subscribe to that for further processing the peak detection.

Comment: And you probably want to use a threshold level for the activity detection because of noise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnPropertyValueChanged` event. Inside this method use the same code as in your while loop.

By the way: Are you aware of the fact, that "Audio Detected" will be print out when user first time reaches level 0? Is it what you want?

Comment: This is just a demo - still need to write the actual action that will take place. Cheers for the tip!

Comment: Neither the MMDevice nor the AudioMeterInformation classes expose an OnPropertyChanged event. And by the way, of course "Audio Detected" will be printed once level is not 0.

Comment: Does this mean a while loop is the best approach then, Dirk? I guess I'd need to reset it once the window was maximised.

Comment: I think pooling in this case is not a bad idea but do some sleep more then 200 ms(to avoid CPU last) and than you can create a property IsDriverChanged and fire the method OnDriverValueChanged when the proerty changed(by set).